# UIImageView vs UIView's drawRect for displaying images

Tags: iphone, ios, graphics

What is the faster way to display images (to maximize FPS)? Setting the image-property of an `UIImageView` or calling `drawAtPoint` of the image within the `drawRect` method (in conjunction with the `setNeedsDisplay` method of the corresponding `UIView`, assuming that the dimensions of the image matches those of the `UIView`)?

Answer (score 1):

While I haven't tested it, I think it is drawAtPoint, especially if you are drawing multiple images into a view.  The overhead of multiple views will be avoided.  If you are just doing a simple animation however UIImageView can be a simple way to do it (see http://appsamuck.com/day2.html). If fps really matters for your application and you have a lot of moving objects, you will want to look into game development tutorials.